# Where does the hierarchical directory structure originate from?

Tags: history, operating-system

Windows, Macintosh, Unix/Linux: today, they all support a hierarchical directory structure. The differences are in the details (mount points vs drive letters), but all use a hierarchical directory structure.

The accepted answer to question [Is there a reason why MS-DOS didn't use more English words for commands?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7685/is-there-a-reason-why-ms-dos-didnt-use-more-english-words-for-commands) says DOS 2.0 added hierarchical directory structure, so I believe Unix had it before DOS.

But was the hierarchical directory structure invented for Unix? Or was there something before Unix that supported a similar hierarchical directory structure?

Comment: Wikipedia claims it was Multics: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multics "Multics was the first Operating System to provide a hierarchical file system"

Comment: One point of note is necessity.  When a medium could only hold 11 files, a hierarchy would not have been necessary and might even have gotten in the way.  But as storage mediums got bigger, a hierarchical structure was going to be inevitable.

Comment: There aren't many good alternative designs to a hierarchical file system - CP/M Plus tried to address the problem of confusingly large amount of files on large  media by the addition of *user areas* which wasn't really practical, but rather, well, *confusing*.

Comment: @tofro what's confusing about user areas? It's basically unhierarchical directories which are numbered, not named.

Comment: @wilson: You do a DIR, find there's (apparently)  no files on the disk, format it - After formatting, you hear your colleague (with another user number) had stored the crown jewels of files on that disk. I think that matches *confusion*.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The first hierarchical system capable of supporting arbitrary directory structures was designed for [Multics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multics), which pre-dates Unix. It is described in [*A General-Purpose File System For Secondary Storage*](https://www.multicians.org/fjcc4.html), although it should be noted that that paper is a design document and doesn’t quite reflect the file system actually implemented a few years later in Multics.

Earlier systems had hierarchical file systems, but not capable of storing arbitrary layouts. [CTSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatible_Time-Sharing_System) (1961) had the concept of directories to some extent, or at least separate storage within the same file system for different users and projects (Dennis M. Ritchie wrote more generally that [“a good case can be made that [Unix] is in essence a modern implementation of MIT’s CTSS system”](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/retro.pdf)).

Comment: To add some words: "non-hierarchical" systems often had at least 2 levels of directories: for each user, a directory of files, and one master directory of user directories.